# Display dialog only if consuming time bigger than 500 milliseconds

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am using `ProgressDialog` in my custom `AsyncTask`, A loading dialog shows up and hides after the time consuming task is done. Sometimes the task can be done quite fast, the dialog appears and disappear right away, it is really bad for user experience, is it possible that display the dialog only if the consuming time bigger than certain time period, for example 500 milliseconds?

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Integer> {
 private ProgressDialog dialog;
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", context.getString(R.string.loading) + "...");
    }


    @Override
    public Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
       //time consuming task is here
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer code) {
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
  }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You can just add a timer in your post execute and dismiss your dialog after 500 milis (or the time you want). If you just want the user to have time to see the dialog.

Comment: @SNt What I want is dont show up the dialog if consuming time smaller than 500 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Handler`, to show a dialog after 500ms. Then in `onPostExecute` you cancel the handler's runnables (if they haven't been run) and hide the dialog (if it was created).

Here's an example:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Integer> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "",
                        context.getString(R.string.loading) + "...");
            }
        }, 500);
    }


    @Override
    public Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //time consuming task is here
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer code) {
        // Remove all runnables from queue
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        // Hide dialog if one exists
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no way to know how long it's going to take and have no idea of the average, I would advice against delaying the dialog as suggested by @user3249477 for the following reason:

Let's say your task can take between 0 and 5000 ms and the odds are constant. The chances your task is done before 500ms are 10%. The chances your task is done between 500ms and 1000ms are also 10%. Displaying a dialog after 500ms useless and the chances it will blink (disappear right away) are the same as before.

My advice: Get to know the average time, and start from there.